# $\|\hat{\beta} - \beta^*\|_2^2$ approximated in big O notation as $O(\|\hat{\beta}\|^2_2)$

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, regression, least-squares, linear-regression

I have a case where I have a linear regression model:
$$y = X\beta^* + w$$ 
where $y \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$,  $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$,  $\beta^* \in \mathbb{R}^{1}$ and $w \sim N(0,I_n), w \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $|\beta^*| \ge 1$ I want to prove that:
$$\|\hat{\beta} - \beta^*\|_2^2 = O(\|\hat{\beta}\|^2_2)$$

Where $\hat{\beta}$ is least squares estimator of $\beta^*$ (formula is $\hat{\beta} = (X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$) and that $|\hat{\beta}| \ge \frac{1}{2}$ is true with probability $1 - O(d^{-10})$ of time.

Can I boldly assume that $\|\hat{\beta} - \beta^*\|_2^2 = O(\|\hat{\beta}\|^2_2)$ is right from looking at the $\beta^*$ as a constant and by extending the square binomial:
$$\|\hat{\beta} - \beta^*\|_2^2 = \|\hat{\beta}\|^2_2 - 2\langle \hat{\beta}, \beta^*\rangle + \|\beta^*\|^2_2 = O(\|\hat{\beta}\|^2_2)$$

Comment: Should you not use $O_p$ instead? Since $\hat{\beta}$ is a sequence of random variables, rather than a deterministic sequence.

Comment: What do you mean by $O_p$?

Comment: This: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_in_probability_notation. Basically, what does your $O$ notation mean if you are dealing with a sequence of random variables?

Comment: I think that the course I am taking doesn't try to be as formal as it should be since it is the fusion of CS and Math department. So I feel they are not making difference between big O notation in deterministic and probabilistic way since all scripts are not mentioning specifically what kind of Big O notation is used, only that it exists, and the course is already over. Did you ever stumble upon these kind of courses where it is not specifically mentioned, or you think I should ask for clarification?

Comment: It might be good for your own understanding to ask for clarification, but if you are simply aiming to pass your exam that might not be necessary. Dropping the probability stuff often makes things a lot easier. I haven't encountered the use of big O notation in stochastics like this, but I do prefer to take more formal courses.

Comment: I just realized that you can interpret this as $||\hat{\beta}-\beta^*||^2 = O(||\hat{\beta}||^2)$ almost surely, which is true in this case, assuming $X$ is non-random.

Comment: Yes, X is assumed to be non-random in our case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $X$ is non-random, $\hat{\beta}$ is a sequence converging to $\beta^*$ a.s. In that case, your argumentation looks fine. A small step that you omit is that
$$| <\hat{\beta}, \beta^*>|\leq ||\hat{\beta}||\cdot ||\beta^*|| = O(||\hat{\beta}||^2),$$
by Cauchy-Schwarz, with the $O(||\hat{\beta}||^2)$ following from the fact that $\beta^*\neq 0.$

Comment: I am not using iterative approach to converge to $\beta^*$, I am using normal equation, so I feel that might be a bad assumption to use this that it arrives there. Maybe assume that there is a constant difference between estimator and true $\beta$ and go with it in the same way as you did?

Comment: I assume that we consider the asymptotic behaviour as $n\to \infty$, right? In that case, you can prove that OLS is strongly consistent. That is, with probability $1$, $\hat{\beta}\to \beta^*$ as $n\to\infty.$

Comment: Yeah, we can agree on that.